# How to use C# stackalloc and keep the same code structure?

Tags: c#, stackalloc

I have a method `MemRead` that reads memory and returns a byte array

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, ref byte lpBuffer, int dwSize, out int lpNumberOfBytesRead);


public static Span<byte> MemRead(this Process process, IntPtr address, int size)
{
if (process == null)
    throw new ArgumentException("Process is null");

Span<byte> buffer = new byte[size];
bool success = NativeMethods.ReadProcessMemory(process.Handle, address, ref MemoryMarshal.GetReference(buffer), size, out int lpNumberOfBytesRead);

if (!success)
    throw new Exception("ReadProcessMemory failed");

if (lpNumberOfBytesRead < size)
    throw new Exception($"ReadProcessMemory failed : {lpNumberOfBytesRead} bytes read out of {size}");

return buffer;
}
```

And I have methods `MemReadInt32`, `MemReadBool`, ... that call `MemRead` and do the conversion

```
public static int MemReadInt32(this Process process, IntPtr address)
{
    return BitConverter.ToInt32(MemRead(process, address, 4));
}
```

Now I want to allocate the buffer on the stack instead of the heap so I change this line

```
Span<byte> buffer = new byte[size];
```

to

```
Span<byte> buffer = stackalloc byte[size];
```

The compiler throws an error because a stack allocated array cannot be exposed outside of the declaration scope. It makes sense this prevents a potential promotion to the heap.

But then I'm forced to place the conversion code in the same method as the reading code. And the reading code will be repeated for each `MemReadInt32`, `MemReadBool`, ...

How can I avoid repeating the `ReadMem` code, and still get stack allocation ?

Comment: You forgot to measure the cost of ReadProcessMemory().  Be ready to be disappointed.

Comment: @HansPassant A quick test shows pinvoke is twice as slow as a native call. That's a trade off I'm willing to accept so I can program in C# instead of C++

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple solution, so I may be missing something, but why don't you take the buffer as a parameter? You could then stackalloc a Span of the right size in the caller function. Otherwise I don't think there is a way as a function's stack space is not accessible after its return (except by passing a pointer out and hoping that the array is still there - though after some testing it never seemed to be - maybe the CLR overwrites it as a safety precaution?)

Comment: @Toni Yes, I would have added this as a comment if I had enough reputation, but I don't see how this doesn't answer the question. Is it that they wrote they "wanted to keep the same code structure"? Because I would argue adding a single `stackalloc byte[n]` to the calls to MemRead would not constitute "changing the code structure", but do tell me if I'm wrong.